# Перенос строки в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Не смог найти ответ на вопрос как перенести строку в файле JSON для увеличения читабельности и вообще удобства, записывать в одну строку длинное значение как-то не очень удобно.

```
//string.json
{
"menu":"Menu:\n
       1 - first\n
       2 - second\n
       3 - third",
"tmp":0
}
```

Как так сделать можно?

Answer (score 8):

Никак, [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) хоть и человекочитаемый формат, но всё-таки предполагается, что он будет генерироваться компьютером и обрабатываться им же.

Добавить в строку символ конца строки можно используя [escape-последовательность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) `\n`:

```
{"key": "line1\nline2"}
```

---

В вашем случае мне кажется стоит изменить структуру json и использовать вложенные объекты:

```
{
    "menu": {
        "1": "first",
        "2": "second",
        "3": "third"
    }
}
```

или вложенные массивы:

```
{
    "menu": [
        "first",
        "second",
        "third"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Как в конечном счете переносить я знаю (подредактирую вопрос), меня интересует именно в файле где хранятся эти данные. Да вложенные объекты это шикарно, но я столкнулся с ситуацией когда надо что бы все было именно в одном ключе...

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, ну и пусть они будут в одну строку.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\n
```

```js
const _dataMenu = '{"menu":"Menu:\\n1 - first\\n2 - second\\n3 - third","tmp":0}'
const _output = JSON.parse(_dataMenu);
console.log(_output.menu);
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Решается легко, следующим образом: В коде принимающей стороны разбиваем на строки и собираем циклом обратно в единую строку но уже с работающими переносами:

```
<body>
   <h1></h1>
</body>

<script>
   let jsonData = {
      "menu":"Menu: \n 1 - first \n 2 - second \n 3 - third"
   }

   jsonData.menu.split("\n").forEach((el) => {
      document.querySelector('h1').innerText += el + '\n';
   })
</script>
```

Если есть доступ к тексту отправляемому в JSON то "\n" можно заменить на любые другие символы, например "***", тогда будет так:

```
<body>
   <h1></h1>
</body>

<script>
   let jsonData = {
      "menu":"Menu:***1 - first***2 - second***3 - third"
   }

   jsonData.menu.split("***").forEach((el) => {
      document.querySelector('h1').innerText += el + '\n';
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**JSON.stringify(json_obj, null, '\t');**

вернёт строку с табуляцией:

```
    {
        "article": {
            "0": {
                "title": "title_0",
                "content": "Hello World 0"
            },
            "1": {
                "title": "title_1",
                "content": "Hello World 1"
            },
            "2": {
                "title": "title_2",
                "content": "Hello World 2"
            }
        }
    }
```

**JSON.stringify(json_obj);**

вернет строку без табуляции в одну строку.

Comment: у автора проблема с длиной значения. Посмотри пример вывода в вопросе. Третий аргумент тут ничем не поможет

Answer (score -1):

Третий аргумент метода JSON.stringify отвечает за форматирование.
Если это число– то уровни вложенности в JSON оформляются указанным количеством пробелов, если строкой – вставляется эта строка.
например: `JSON.stringify({obj}, null, 4)`

Comment: у автора проблема с длиной _значения_. Посмотри пример вывода в вопросе. Третий аргумент тут ничем не поможет